# How to convert Text to HTML in JavaScript function and unit test it with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, text-to-html

I have found a JavaScript function which converts text to HTML.
Here is the function

```
export default function ToText(node) {
  let tag = document.createElement("div");
  tag.innerHTML = node;
  node = tag.innerText;
  return node;
}
```

I tried to test the function, but it is not working correctly. Here is my Testing script

```
import ToText from '../ToText';

it('check whether ToText function is working or not', () => {
  const a = "<P>This is a mock test for this function.</P>";
  const b = `This is a mock test for this function`;

  expect(ToText(a)).toBe(b);
});
```

What could be the reason it is not working, please help ?

Comment: Please see the answer posted now

Answer (score 0):

Variable a has a dot(.) at the end of the string.
Variable b does not have it.

Comment: That dot is not a matter

Comment: But please remove it as you are doing string comparison

Answer (score 0):

Just do this it might get solved

```
node= tag.firstChild.innerText
```

Comment: Does this helpful

Comment: I can't change the code. I can only change the test

Comment: Then you have to remove the tag inside the a variable

Comment: const a = "This is a mock test for this function";

Comment: I tested it it did worked for me though just a min I am posting the code without test in a snippet

Comment: check this out https://jsbin.com/famutuf/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: This is not a test case as i did not find any editor online so used plain javascript

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the plain text and not with the HTML.
The ToText function is returning the innerText. If you want to change the changes you did then the ToText function needs to be changed.

```
import ToText from '../ToText';

it('check whether ToText function is working or not', () => {
  const a = "This is a mock test for this function";

  expect(ToText(a)).toBe(a);
});
```